# Understanding ט"ז in יורה דעה קפ"ב

Tags: halacha, shaving, yoreh-deah, lo-yilbash

Does anyone have any idea, what does the Taz in [Yoreh Deah 182:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.182.1?lang=he&with=Turei%20Zahav&lang2=he) mean? I see the [Hagohas haTaz](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5172) tries to elaborate, but I really don’t understand that either. Is he trying to differentiate between razoring the head and the rest of the body, or maybe between razoring just one part of a limb?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dov and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: There is an error in the text in sefaria בכל עקום instead of בכל מקום I corrected it

Comment: Please cite the source in the question. Links always break and the question becomes obslete.

Comment: I'm glad to see such advanced questions. Can you next time share some background and try to grapple with the text?

Answer (score 2):

It had just stated that for a man to shave his underarms or pubic area would be prohibited as a gender-bending practice. The Taz's reading of the next line is "she'ar" -- *but one may shave any other part of their body with a razor-like scissor*.

A variant text would be *sei'ar* -- which would read: *no shaving underarm or pubic with a razor-like scissors; but plain old scissors can be used on any hair on the body.*

Comment: I dont understand! Theres two גירסת in the shulchan aruch?

Comment: Your explanation is of Taz #2, but I think he's asking about Taz #1 (he wrote "I see the Hagohas haTaz tries to elaborate" which is on #1)

Comment: @dovkinderman It happens, you know... even in the bible...

Comment: As @ba said you don't answer the OP's question. erase your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Taz refers to a disagreement reported by the Tur between Rabenu Tam and others regarding shaving the body with a blade and with scissors.

The Tur;

> העברת תער בשאר הגוף ובית השחי ובית הערוה,‏
>
> פר"ת שדינן שוה, שאסורין בתער ומותרין במספריים.‏
>
> וי"א דוקא בשאר הגוף מותר במספריים, אבל של בית השחי ושל בית הערוה אסורין אפילו במספריים. וכן הוא מסקנת אדוני אבי הרא"ש ז"ל.‏

1. Regarding underharm and pubic area. For Rabenu Tam, to shave with scissors is permitted, with a blade it's prohibited.  Following the second opinion it's prohibited even with scissors.
2. Regarding the last parts of the body, except for the head, Rabenu Tam prohibits with a blade and the second opinion allows with scissors and prohibits with a blade.

The Taz says refers the opinion of Rabenu Yona quoted in Bet Yosef suman 181

> וכ"כ ה"ר יונה … אבל אסרו חכמים להעביר שער בתער בכ"מ בגוף ואפי' על זרועותיו לפי שדומה לתיקון הנשים אבל מותר להעבירו במספרים עכ"ל

The Taz says that the line of Rabenu Yona differs from the the two opinion quoted by the Tur.

But at first glance, this is the second opinion of the Tur. This difficulty is addressed by the Hagahot Hataz.

So, the Hagahot Hataz explains that the Taz understands that since in the Tur when the non pubic and axillary area is treated, there is no mention  for partial surface, the prohibition to shave the body with a blade regards only the case in which the entire surface of the body is shaved (here we don't consider the head that have special rules for hairs and beard). But to shave one area, e.g. the chest or forearms is permitted. Since, the opinion of Rabenu Yona is a third opinion because he says that to shave arms is prohibited with a blade.

Let's examine the Hagaot Hataz.

> כי הטור לא זכר אבר בשאר הגוף אלא סתם בכל הגוף והיינו כל הגוף דהוא מותר במספריים
>
> The Tur didn't address the case in which they shave one member of the last part of the body. i.e. an area that is not the pubis or the axillary.
>
> כדאיתא בגמרא מקיל אדם בכל גופו וכו' הוא הדין נמי לענין איסור תער ותו
>
> The Tur uses the language of the Gemara, "Rab said: A man may thin [the hair of] his whole body with a razor." and this is true even for the rule of shaving with a blade
>
> דאם נתפרש מה שכתב הטור בשאר הגוף היינו אפילו מקצת ממנו אפילו לא אבר שלם דאם לא כן היה לו להזכיר אחד מן האברים
>
> If we try to explain the Tur wrote "the last body" means "one part of the last body", even a single part of the body, even a part of a member, it's wrong, because, to be clear, he must to mention "one of the members"
>
> וזו ודאי שרי אפילו בתער אפילו בשחיוערוה ואפילו גבי זקן כמו דמשמע מדברי הטור סימן קפ"א בשם הרא"ש
>
> And to shave a part of a member (a part of a specific area) is obviously permitted, even for the axillary area and the pubic area, and even for the beard, as we understand from the words of the Tur in siman 181 in name of the Rosh
>
> אלא ודאי דעל כל הגוף קאמר
>
> So, obviously, the Tur means the whole body
>
> והיינו בלא הראש דאילו עם הראש אין זה יפוי כמו שאכתוב בסמוך ומשום הכי דוקא יש איסור בתע
>
> And when he wrote the body, this doesn't include the head, because the prohibition to shave the body is a prohibition to make himself beautiful; and for this reason, for the last body the prohibition is only with a blade (tha makes the skin smooth).

Comment: Also, you force that R"Y disagrees only with the 2nd opinion , but in the Tur it says דעות,  not דעה. see my answer.

Comment: For Rabenu Tam fixed.

Comment: Rabenu Tam disagrees with the pshat of Rabenu Tam in the second opinion

Comment: Did you mean "Rabenu Yona disagrees with..." ? anyway. I don't think so. I think That  Hagahot Htaz understand immediately that the Tur (both opinions) talks about the entire body only. He does not discuss over it. That's the difference between our answers.

Comment: He disagrees with both opinions and obviously the Taz thinks that there is no discrepancy between the both opinions in the Tur because they are not different regarding the lack of reference to one isolated arm or leg

Comment: But I referred to the second opinion because of the similarity at first glance between the two

Comment: So the tur would allow according to both opinions to use a razor on a part of your shechi or erva? Also what exactly does he mean by the rosh at the end?

Comment: Yes, see edit..

Answer (score 2):

***Good question, it takes a real effort to understand what he meant***

First, you should read the sources that the T"Z talks about!

At the end of the last chapter, the T"Z quotes the Beis Yossef the brings Rabinu Yona. He says the shaving with **razor** is forbidden anywhere.

The T"Z states that this opinion disagrees the opinion in the Tur in our chapter.

Now, what opinion the Tur talks about?

The Hagohas haTaz explanation:

> העברת תער בשאר הגוף ובית השחי ובית הערוה, פר"ת שדינן שוה, שאסורין בתער
>   ומותרין במספריים

Shaving with razor the rest of the body is like the armpit and the pubic, it's forbidden with razor but allowed with scissors.

The Hagohas haTaz explains that this rule only apply if you shave your entire body, aside from the head with razor - then it's forbidden, but one region is OK!!
He understands "rest of the body" - "the **entire** rest of the body", not "any part from the rest of the body", see the end of his chapter.

So, he tries to differentiate one region from the entire body, aside from the head.